# Do I have to run sphinx-apidoc for each new module (file)?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Trying to get familiar with Sphinx, I am used to documentation using Doxygen where it auto generates stubs and classes from your source.

With Sphinx it seems for each new module/file I have to run `sphinx-apidoc -o dir dir` just like you have to `git add file` in git, is this standard or is there a setting flag I am missing.

I know I can automate a bash/bat file to do run each command in sequence. I am curious if I am doing something wrong.

Just in case someone asks I do have those extensions turned on and imported the local path.

**conf.py**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
]
```

Comment: You don't *have* to run sphinx-apidoc at all. You only need at least one *.rst file with automodule (autoclass, autofunction) directives that "pull in" the sources that you want to document.

Comment: Yes I saw something like that, an .RTS with autoloading all automodules. Do you have source for this? Sphinx documentation is fuzzy at best.

Comment: sphinx-apidoc is a convenience script that autogenerates *.rst files containing `automodule` directives. You don't have to use the script. You can create the *.rst files "by hand". I'm not sure what you mean by "autoloading all automodules", but the documentation for the autodoc extension is here: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run `sphinx-apidoc` for each file.

> sphinx-apidoc generates source files that use sphinx.ext.autodoc to document all found modules. [sphinx-apidoc-manual-page](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#sphinx-apidoc-manual-page)

so if your project is organized as standard python modules, which basically means you've added `__init__.py` file in each module folder. `sphinx-apidoc` should find them automatically.

Comment: So If I have  2 .py files and those have an RTS skeleton, If I create another module (file) do I not have to run sphinx-apidoc to generate new .rts

Comment: My flow right now is  run `sphinx-apidoc` and `make html` then if I add a new file to the project I have to  run `sphinx-apidoc` again then `make html`

Comment: @c3cris you need run it again, but only once. My point here is you don't need to run the command for each file. If your project is importable, `sphinx-api` will generate .rst files for all newly added modules. If you already knew that, maybe I  misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, I run `sphinx-apidoc` only once (1) for any new file(s). Just the same way you run `git add` when attempting to track new files. Is my assumption correct? Why isn't this automated, and I mean from the sphinx mod to detect new files and generate new .rst?